# Angular app raises undefined on this.resizeSubscription$.unsubscribe

Tags: ios, angular

I am developing an angular app using angular 10. It works fine but I have an error on iOS. If I Safari or Google Chrome I receive the following error:

`Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.resizeSubscription$.unsubscribe')`

I reproduces this by navigating through the app. After 5-10 clicks this error is raised and it gets stuck.

Have you encountered this problem?

My dependencies:

```
    "@angular/animations": "~10.1.0",
    "@angular/common": "~10.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~10.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "~10.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~10.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~10.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~10.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "~10.1.0",
    "@angular/service-worker": "~10.1.0",
    "@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "0.7.0",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.30",
    "@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "^5.13.0",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.14.0",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^13.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^6.0.0",
    "bootstrap": "4.5.2",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "ng-cloudimage-responsive": "^2.1.3",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "5.2.0",
    "ngx-skeleton-loader": "^2.4.4",
    "ngx-toastr": "^13.0.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.4",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
```

Best regards

Comment: You might want to post some relevant code.. ?

Comment: I can't figure out when this error happens, I didn't directly use any resizeSubscription. Maybe it is worth mentioning that i have added the pwa module to my project

Comment: If a global code search for ‘ resizeSubscription’ doesn’t yield any results.. then I’m not sure where to start with debugging..

Comment: Yes, global search doesn't yield any result :(

Comment: Do you use SSR..?

Comment: No, I'm not using SSR

Comment: Must be a third party package then..? Any UI related package that could be using resize kinda logic..? This is a though one man.. a google search also doesn’t give much useful results..

Comment: I updated my question with my dependencies. I don't think that anything can influence this.

Comment: I think I found it though.. ng-cloudimage-responsive is probably the culprit: https://github.com/scaleflex/ng-cloudimage-responsive/blob/master/projects/lib/src/lib/img/img.component.ts (line 77)

Comment: Yeah, you are right. Thanks :D